# Authentication using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-post

As we all know that using `GET` method for login (or sending sensitive information) is not suggested. I want to create login functionality using XMLHTTPRequest. Following are my steps:

1. User enters username and password and clicks on Submit button
2. Submit button invokes an XMLHTTPRequest
3. XMLHTTPRequest sends the credential to a PHP page which will verify
   it
4. If credentials are right then create session otherwise show error message
   without refreshing the login screen.

**My question is:**

How can I transfer login credentials to a PHP page using `POST` (securely)? If I am using the `open` method as shown below with `GET` then I think it is not secure. Can I replace `GET` with `POST`? If yes, then how to transfer credentials?

`xmlhttp.open("GET","verifyCredentials.php",true);`

Comment: Use a secure connection using HTTPS, it's the only way to ensure a user's credentials can't be sniffed. Why do you want to use an XMLHttpRequest in the first place? What's the advantage it has over sending a normal form using Post(/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: @Marcel: I want to use XMLHTTPRequest because it will verify the credentials in background and will show error in case wrong password is provided without refreshing the page

Comment: But you'll have to send a new page after a correct log in, won't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post data using POST method, set the method in [`open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) to `POST`, set the *Content-Type* request header field to [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), encode your data accordingly, and pass it as parameter value to [`send`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "verifyCredentials.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

You can use the `encodeURIComponent` function to encode your data:

```
function formUrlEncoded(params) {
    var data = "";
    for (var name in params) {
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
        if (data.length) data += "&";
        data += (encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(param)).replace(/%20/g, "+");
    }
    return data;
}
var data = formUrlEncoded({"foo":"bar", "baz":"quux"});
```

Note that with this the data is still transferred unprotected against eavesdropping.

Comment: What do you mean by encoding data? Suppose username, password are given as parameters `uname, pass` to my XMLHTTPRequest function. How can I encode?

Comment: @iSumitG: you should always properly encode query parameters in JavaScript using `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @iSumitG: POST data requires a special encoding/formatting. For simple form data, [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) is assumed; multipart form data requires [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

Comment: But this is not secure, it only url encodes the user credentials. Essentially it is cleartext.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference of `POST` and `GET` is that `POST` sends the data in the http-body and not in the URL (headers), so both methods are not "secure" for transmitting login credentials.
As mentioned, you should use [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol_Secure).

Answer (score 0):

Send the md5 of the passwords in the password field. Then, on the server, you can further obfuscate it if you want.

Comment: That's not secure if you're not using HTTPS: it doesn't matter whether you send a hashed password or plain text, it can be sniffed and later used to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do authentication over an insecure channel (you are not using HTTPS) you could use an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) based login protocol. HMAC can be used for [user authentication](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HmacUserAuthentication).

I have an implementation of this available in [Javascript](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/media/js/login.js) (client) and [Python](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/middleware/auth.py) (server side). You can use that as an example to start with, or find another implementation. There is probably a PHP implementation of it somewhere, but you will likely have to modify it for your needs.